# Show that $x^\frac{1}{n}$ is continuous at all $a \in [0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, continuity

I have to show $x^\frac{1}{n}$ is continuous using:
$|x-a| = |(x^\frac{1}{n})^n - (a^\frac{1}{n})^n| = |x^\frac{1}{n} - a^\frac{1}{n}||\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x^\frac{1}{n})^{n-1-k} + (a^\frac{1}{n})^{k} |$

Here's what I did:

$a=0$:

$|x^\frac{1}{n}| < \epsilon => |x| < \epsilon^n$
Pick $\delta = \epsilon^n$, and we have $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$

$a>0$:

$|x-a| = |x^\frac{1}{n} - a^\frac{1}{n}||\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x^\frac{1}{n})^{n-1-k} + (a^\frac{1}{n})^{k}| < \epsilon \cdot |\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (x^\frac{1}{n})^{n-1-k} + (a^\frac{1}{n})^{k}|$

Since this sum evaluates to a real number $R > 0$, we can pick $\delta = R\epsilon $  and we get:

$0<|x-a| < \delta => |x^\frac{1}{n} - a^\frac{1}{n}| < \epsilon$

Is this correct or is there anything else I need to show?
Also, this is my first time formatting with MathJax, so if there are any errors please let me know!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715909/proof-that-fx-x1-n-is-continuous?rq=1

Comment: @GAUSS1860 Yeah I saw that post before I posted this thread. I have to use that factorization of |x-a| to show that the function is continuous, so that thread doesn't help much. I was wondering if my work is rigorous enough a proof or if there are any errors with it. 
Thanks!

Comment: You need the correct factorization and further on in the argument  it is not enough to say that the sum is a number $R$ because in this form it still depends on $x$.  You need to find a bound that depends only on $a$ (and perhaps $n$) to prove continuity at $a$.

Comment: Otherwise you have basically the correct idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need the correct factorization

$$x- a = (x^{\frac{1}{n}} - a^{\frac{1}{n}})\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{n-1-k}{n}} a^{\frac{k}{n}}$$

Whence,

$$|x^{\frac{1}{n}} - a^{\frac{1}{n}}|= \frac{|x-a|}{\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{n-1-k}{n}} a^{\frac{k}{n}} \right|} $$

Note that by the reverse triangle inequality $|a|- |x| \leqslant |x-a|$ which implies that $|x| \geqslant |a| - |x-a|$.

If $a > 0$ and $|x-a| \leqslant \frac{a}{2}$, then we have $x = |x| \geqslant |a| - |x-a| \geqslant a - \frac{a}{2} = \frac{a}{2}.$

Hence, $\displaystyle x^{\frac{n-1-k}{n}} a^{\frac{k}{n}} \geqslant 2^{\frac{k}{n}}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{1 - \frac{1}{n}},$ and

$$\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{n-1-k}{n}} a^{\frac{k}{n}} \right|\geqslant  \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2 ^{\frac{k}{n}}  = \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{1 - \frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{n}} -1} := C_n$$

It follows that if  $|x-a| < \delta = \min\left(\epsilon C_n, \frac{a}{2}\right)$, then

$$|x^{\frac{1}{n}} - a^{\frac{1}{n}}|\leqslant \frac{|x-a|}{C_n} < \epsilon,$$

and $x \mapsto x^{\frac{1}{n}}$
is continuous at $a > 0$.

Comment: The error in the factorization was just a typing error, I copy-pasted the sum over and over so it just carried :D. Thanks a ton for everything!

Comment: @KailashSeshadri: You're welcome.